# Making the Content Editor Box Bigger in 2013

Tags: editor, wysiwyg

I know that question have been answer, but answer is no more current

with wp 3.5.2 (or 3.6) and many plugin, qtranslate first... i dont have the "size of the post box" in Settings > Writing. Yes i can manually extent the box with the lower right triagle, but when saved, it's back to super small 2-3 line in height

So the question, how do i change it PERMANANTLY to 30 line in height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a small plugin to give ability for user to change the edito height in a option of profile page. A sort of back in time to WP < 3.5.2

### Workflow

1. Create custom field in the profile settings
2. On admin init check if we are in the right page, if so set an hook for the filter `the_editor`
3. In funcion hooken into `the_editor` get the user option and use a regex replace to change height, only if the id of the editor is the right one to prevent plugin interfer with other calls of `wp_editor`

### Edit

I've created a better version of the original posted plugin. It's almost the same but is coded in a class and give 2 options for editor height: one for desktops one for mobile devices.
The code can be found in **[this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/6302022#file-gmcustomeditorheight-php)**.

Plugin in quickly tested on WP 3.6 and seems to work.

Below a preview of how this plugin let set the options:

[image]

Comment: i see it work, but it's (in second) overwrittend by qtranslate a become small again ! :-(

Comment: Damn! qtranslate is a bad plugin! I'm joking, but I think qtranslate use js to resize, and the only way to block it is probably another js or disable qtranslate and start usign [wpml](http://wpml.org) that is much better! :) @menardmam

Answer (score 0):

if you add this style to this file, you will change it permanently.

Add the following to the functions.php file of your theme.

add this style;

```
<?php
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );
?>
```

Create **custom-editor-style.css** file on theme directory.add following code.

```
.wp_themeSkin iframe{
          height: 800px!important;
    }
```

you can change height value whatever you want.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style

Comment: I changed my reply.

Comment: Sorry, id doesn't work. Cite from the codex page you linked (bold mine): _"Any CSS rules added to that file will be reflected **within** the TinyMCE visual editor"_  So it works inside the editor, cannot change the editor itself.